# return view based on getimagesize - react-native

Tags: reactjs, image, react-native, conditional-statements

I have the following piece of code:

```
getPhoto(item) {

Image.getSize( 'http://api/people/' + item.id + '/photo', ( width, height ) =>
{
  this.setState({ imageWidth: width, imageHeight: height });
  console.log('http://api/people/' + item.id + '/photo', + ' ' +  'width: ' + width)
},(errorMsg) =>
{ 
  console.log('http://api/people/' + item.id + '/photo', + ' ' + ' errorMsg: ' + errorMsg.code);
  this.setState({ imageError: errorMsg.code });
});

//console.log('http://api/people/' + item.id + '/photo', + ' ' + ' errorMsg: ' + this.state.imageError + ' ' + ' errorMsgIncludes: ' + this.state.imageError.includes('ERCTERRORDOMAIN0'));

return (  
   <TouchableOpacity>
      <ListItem style={styles.listItem}>

        <FastImage
          style={styles.avatar}
          source={{
            uri: 'http://api/people/' + item.id + '/photo',
            priority: FastImage.priority.high,
          }}
          resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.strech}
        />

        <View style={styles.multiLineView} >
          <Text style={styles.name}>{item.id}</Text>
        </View>

      </ListItem>
    </TouchableOpacity>
)
```

}

The problem here is that the setstate does not persist outside of the success and error callbacks and hence i am getting inappropriate results.

How can i render a view from within those callback functions?

Thanks in advance for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should refactor your code a little bit and move the get photo function logic to a new component

```
export default class Item extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
       super(props);
       this.state={imageWidth: 0, imageHeight: 0}
     }
   // make the call for get size inside component did mount
   componentDidMount(){
      let item = this.props.item;
     Image.getSize( 'http://api/people/' + item.id + '/photo', ( width, height 
       ) =>
      {
      this.setState({ imageWidth: width, imageHeight: height });
       console.log('http://api/people/' + item.id + '/photo', + ' ' +  'width: 
     ' + width)
      },(errorMsg) =>
      { 
        console.log('http://api/people/' + item.id + '/photo', + ' ' + ' errorMsg: ' + errorMsg.code);
        this.setState({ imageError: errorMsg.code });
      });
   }

   render(){
      // render the view you want here according to the component state
      switch(this.state.acondition){
         case 1:
         return a view or component you want ...
         etc ...
      }
   }
}
```

and then you can call the component and pass the item like this

```
import Item from './Item';

<Item item={item}/>
```